# Firebase security rules warnings

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have updated the rules according to the document and I didn't get any errors and its working fine. But I am getting warnings in my database from the past few days. What may be the reason?

Please help me

[image: my Database with documents][image: These are my rules for the collection "User"]

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire set of rules for your project.  The warning is telling you that your rules allow full read and write access to that document, which means you probably wrote something in your rules that's different than what you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson Please look into it, I have added the rules image

Comment: When adding code to a question, please copy the code directly into the question rather than showing a screenshot so that it's easier to search and read.

Answer (score 0):

The warning message says "Any signed-in user can read or write this document".  Your rules are allowing exactly that.  When you say:

```
match /User/{AuthID=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
}
```

That rule is saying that signed-in user can read and write the document.  If that's not what you want, then change your rule, or just ignore the warning message if this is OK.